# How to connect a search engine to mahout

Tags: php, mysql, hadoop, mahout-recommender

I have a search engine and I want to it just search special words for example when you search `c vitamins the` the search engine should bring the contents and when you click on the contents, it should bring its `harm sides`. Such as `c vitamin is bad for blah blah`.

Is it possible to connect a search engine created in php to Apache mahout?

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use mahout? I am not quit sure about your scenario , please provide more details.
From your description, I get the impression that you kind of want to recommend a static data . I mean all the content and harm sides are pre-populated and kept somewhere and then you fetch the info based on your search query. Is this the case? If yes , then I do not think you need Mahout for this. If this is not your case , please provide more details.

Mahout recommender is used for making analytical recommendations. For example mahout's Collaborative filtering recommendations are based on  tuples. Using this you can make user-based (users similar to you searched XXX or bought YYYY) or item-based (people who searched TTT also searched ZZZZ) recommendations. There are also other types of recommendations that you can make using mahout but as I said before they all needs some input data and analysis.

Comment: Hello, I want a semantic search engine, it must find clever and relevant queries, for example when I type "kitchen" word into the search box the search result must be food additives and diet menu, I don't want the result to be ikea kitchen or tables so on. The search engine I want is going to use Hadoop or Impala to fetch data from RDBMS to Hadoop and map reduce the unstructured data into structured data...

Comment: Let me do a little bit research on this. I will get back to you on weekend.